# Extract data from Google docs to Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, documentation

I am working within the same Google drive folder. 
I have a number of Google Docs, which all contains a number of tables in the same format. What I want is to export the data from each table in to according rows in a google spreadsheet. I think the function should be automated to run ones every day. The first problem I am bumping in on is to open the different Doc files and extract the tables - any surgestions on how to do that?

The folder is access protected, but both the Docs and Sheet are placed within the same folder.

BR.
Torben

Comment: Use the Apps Script "Drive Service." An internet search for guides, examples, and reference documentation will get you started. When you have an attempt at using the class, please edit your question to reflect the specific programming question you are unable to solve. https://stack overflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome. The question is too broad for this site. Ref. [ask]. I you didn't this yet, go to https://developers.google.com/apps-script and checkout the quickstarts and  guides and search for related questions on this site, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/34857892/1595451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the Drive API and export the documents as HTML. Then you will need to parse the HTML yourself to extract the table data. Finally use the Sheets API to insert that data into your spreadsheet.